# Cisco Router: select outbound gateway based on the source IP

Tags: cisco, ip, routing

I have a network which is currently using a Microtik AH493 as the edge device.  This uses IPTable for routing and packet manipulation, and we're using policy routing to select the appropriate outbound interface based on the source IP.

In simple form for any traffic going to the outside world:

if (source IP in (AddressList) ) then (use gateway1)
else (use gateway2)

Is there any equivalent to this in Cisco IOS?  We're looking at using a Cisco 1941 as a replacement, provided we can handle this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, PBR is a standard feature on the Cisco Router 1900 series.  I have 2 sites with 1900 series routers currently setup with PBR.  Check out [these](http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-use-cisco-ios-policy-based-routing-features.htm) [articles](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/qcfpbr_ps1835_TSD_Products_Configuration_Guide_Chapter.html) for more info.